# Different timezone clocks without PHP?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make two different clocks on my page, one that just follows the DK time as standard and one that follows the local time of the user. Then I thought, can I do this without PHP? So far I can't find anything with JS that will lock the timezone for the DK watch without changing it when the time on the user's computer is changed. Is there a function in JS that can do that or do I need PHP?

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="clock">
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <div id="daymonth"></div>
    <div id="year"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="clock">
    <span class="offset"></span>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <div id="daymonth2"></div>
    <div id="year2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var date = new Date(),
  offset = date.getTimezoneOffset()/60,
  year = date.getFullYear(),
  month = date.getMonth(),
  day = date.getUTCDate(),
  months = ["Januar", "Febuar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  function pad(number, length) {
    var str = "" + number
    while (str.length < length) {
      str = '0' + str
    }
    return str
  }
  document.getElementById('daymonth').innerHTML = months[month] + " " + day;
  document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = year;
  document.getElementById('daymonth2').innerHTML = months[month] + " " + day;
  document.getElementById('year2').innerHTML = year;
  var clockH = $(".hours");
  var clockM = $(".minutes");
  var clockS = $(".seconds");
  var clockO = $(".offset");

  function time() {
    var d = new Date(),
    s = d.getSeconds() * 6,
    m = d.getMinutes() * 6 + (s / 60),
    h = d.getHours() % 12 / 12 * 365 + (m / 12);
    clockH.css("transform", "rotate(" + h + "deg)");
    clockM.css("transform", "rotate(" + m + "deg)");
    clockS.css("transform", "rotate(" + s + "deg)");
  }

  function timezone() {
    var t = new Date(),
    s = t.getSeconds() * 6,
    m = t.getMinutes() * 6 + (s / 60),
    o = t.getHours() % 12 / 12 * 365 + offset + (m / 12)-60;
    clockO.css("transform", "rotate(" + o + "deg)");
    clockM.css("transform", "rotate(" + m + "deg)");
    clockS.css("transform", "rotate(" + s + "deg)");
  }

  var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);
  time();
  var clock = setInterval(timezone, 1000);
  timezone();
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8qgx0Lx/

Comment: You want to get rid of PHP by tagging PHP? ;)

Comment: ... Just understood the irony :) Ill remove the php tag thanks :)

Comment: Stop trying to use javascript dates, use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). It rocks and it happens that it also handles timezones.

Comment: So primarily what i wanted is already made as a "plugin" ?

Comment: Thanks alot Florian F. for the link looks like it has what I need so far. :)